# Can I add a personal launcher to favourite toolbox in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10.

Is it possible to add a personal launcher to favorite toolbox in GNOME Shell 3.2?

I've installed Firefox from pre-compiled binaries and Longman dictionary but cannot manage to add launcher to favorites.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112186/how-do-you-create-a-custom-application-launcher-in-gnome-shell

Answer (score 9):

You could copy your launcher to ~/.local/share/applications, or use the one below:

Here's a sample:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Web Browser2
Comment=Firefox Web Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
Exec=/my/path/to/run_mozilla
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Internet;
MimeType=text/plain;
StartupNotify=true
```

If you save this as, say, Firefox_custom.desktop in ~/.local/share/applications it will show up in your gnome overview and then you'll be able to drag it as a favorite.

**Edit:**

Guess I'll add some extra information based off Luigi's comment.

An easy way to create a .desktop file in the proper directory is using `gtk-desktop-item-edit` like so:

```
gtk-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/.local/share/applications
```

Comment: Great thank you! 
I've created a launcher with this command: 
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Scrivania/ --create-new
and then copied the .desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications

Comment: @Luigi don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 6):

You can also use alacarte:

> sudo apt-get install alacarte

Alacarte is a program that creates and edits menu entries in a graphical way.