# How do you create a custom application launcher in Gnome Shell?  

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop

How do you create a custom application launcher in Gnome Shell?

I have a local Eclipse installation that I'd like to be to quickly launch. So I created a symlink to the `eclipse` binary and placed it on my desktop. If I open a terminal, `cd` to ~/Desktop and run `./eclipse` it starts Eclipse perfectly. However, if I click the Eclipse icon on my desktop, and choose `run`, nothing happens.

Alternatively, I wouldn't mind being able to search for Eclipse on the "Activities" screen, but I can't find any documentation on adding or registering custom applications.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Try to create a `eclipse.desktop` file under `/usr/share/applications` (or `~/.local/share/applications` or directly in `~/Desktop`) with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse IDE
Exec=/path/to/eclipse/executable
Icon=/path/to/eclipse/icon
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
```

You can choose another category, too. For additional information: [categories available](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html).

Comment: Thanks. The only problem I ran into, which the docs don't mention, is that the file has to be executable if you place it in ~/Desktop. Otherwise it just shows up as an ordinary text file and isn't launchable or rendered with the right icon.

Comment: You might find that you need to restart gnome3 for this to take effect, especially the icon. If so, run Alt+F2, type `r` in the box, and press enter.

Comment: Your application may require a working directory, use `Path=/path/to/eclipse/working-dir`.

Answer (score 20):

Although creating your own launcher by hand is a valid solution, my preferred one is to go through [`alacarte`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alacarte) and create a new entry on the menus, then it will appear as a launcher.

Comment: Thanks, I could not believe my eyes that to add a simple entry in my modern Desktop environment, i needed to create a 10-lines text file in a hidden directory in my home folder, by hand. This should be the winning answer.

Comment: Once you've created a new launcher in the menu, you can search for it in the activities screen and then drag it to your panel.

Comment: @CodeKid Yeah that's what I meant :)

Comment: I've added a blog post on what is the exact name and how to use it.

Comment: The link in this is dead and takes you to Lifewire's home page. Suggest removing or updating the link, it looks sus.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I have found to create launchers using a full-featured GUI is vie MenuLibre, which is in the Ubuntu repositories. It will hold your hand through the process and allow you to create a custom launcher in a fast and straightforward manner, as long as you know where your resources reside (binary location, icon location, working directories, etc). Alacarte does not work reliably for me.

Answer (score 3):

In newer Gnome versions `Comment` and `Terminal` sections become mandatory so minimal `.desktop` file is now:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Sample Application Name
Comment=A sample application
Exec=application
Icon=application.png
Terminal=false
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list of custom launchers you can access from the panel you could use the MyLauncher extension. 
[MyLauncher Gnome Shell Extension](http://markbokil.com/downloads/extensions/mylauncher/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want proper shortcut, then do following:

1. go to /usr/share/applications
2. coppy one of the *.desktop files to this location with the name you intend to use as application name;
3. adjust the executable path
4. adjust the icon path
   5! check carefully for all the places in this file where old references are, and edit them to your needs.