# What is Sweet Home 3D and how to install it?

Tags: software-installation

I am currently using Sweet home 3D for modeling my home.

It will be nice if someone adds in more detail about this software and how to install in on Ubuntu.

Also is it possible to change the units from meters to square feet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sweet home 3D is in the software Center. All you have to do to install it is open the Ubuntu Software Center, search for "Sweet Home 3D" and click the 'install' button.
If you want to know more about the software,you can visit it's [official website](http://www.sweethome3d.com).

To change the units from the metric to the imperial system, there is an option in the preferences.
In the 'File' menu click 'Preferences' and change the unit option to whatever you prefer.

Comment: But this will install older version (4.4) while there is a new one (5.0). It is very difficult to install latest version and I don't know how.

Answer (score 4):

**What is Sweet Home 3D?**

Sweet Home 3D is a free architectural design software application that helps you place your furniture on a house 2D plan, with a 3D preview.In Sweet Home 3D, you can import furniture and arrange pieces of furniture to create a virtual environment. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_Home_3D)

**How to install Sweet Home 3D?**

- Using official Ubuntu repos (always some versions behind):

  - [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sweethome3d/).
  - Using terminal : `sudo apt install sweethome3d`
- From [official website](http://www.sweethome3d.com/download.jsp)

  - Download **Linux 64-bit installer**
  - Uncompress: `tar -zxvf SweetHome3D-6.1.2-linux-x64.tgz`
  - Move: `sudo mv SweetHome3D-6.1.2/ /opt/`
  - [Create icon](https://askubuntu.com/a/920078/349837):

    - <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd>, Run *alacarte*
    - Clic on *New item* and create it: 
      [image: screenshot]
  - You then may want to [add more 3D models](http://www.sweethome3d.com/importModels.jsp#ModelsLibraries).

Dependencies: Java

Comment: Any particular reason you are promoting this software? This Q&A reads just like a content farm.

Comment: @TomBrossman Found this software good and I am not promoting this software by any means :) Initially found it bit difficult to get start with it. So by adding few information, thought we can help others in the community.