# Change command to launch firefox in 18.10

Tags: firefox, 18.10

I'm running Firefox on Ubuntu 18.10 with a laptop that has a touchscreen. Apparently, Firefox needs to be told to support this by launching it with this command:

> MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 /usr/bin/firefox

Now I normally launch firefox using the search key and then typing "firefox" followed by enter. How can I keep that process and have it launch with the xinput2 params I need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

Comment: Since GNOME is used instead of Unity, suggest looking at https://askubuntu.com/questions/112186/how-do-you-create-a-custom-application-launcher-in-gnome-shell/920078

Comment: Found a workaround for needing the custom launcher. The Arch Wiki has the details: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox/Tweaks#Enable_touchscreen_gestures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create your own new .desktop file by running

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefoxtouch.desktop
```

substitute gedit with any text editor you prefer

Now, put inside those file

```
    [Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Touch
Comment=
Exec=env MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 /usr/bin/firefox %u
Icon=firefox
Terminal=false
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

and save. Now searching for Firefox should five you another entry for Firefox with custom parameter you need.

Comment: That works well, except searching now brings up both versions. Any way to consolidate so I only see one of them?

Comment: If you have root access you can edit "system" one instead of creating your personal.
"/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop" is system one. However i advise you against doing that - on each version update you will have to reedit it again.
Maybe giving it somehow unique name is option?