# How to create a icon to execute a script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, icons

I installed an `android-studio` on my machine. But I only need the `emulator`, not the whole `android-studio`.

I can run my `emulator` from `Terminal` using the following command

```
cd /home/bmshamsnahid/Android/Sdk/emulator && ./emulator -avd Pixel_2_XL_API_29
```

How can I use an `icon`? So I can open the `Emulator` by `clicking` the `icon`.

Internally, whenever I click the `icon`, the `script` will be executed.

Can you provide any guidelines or terms I can look for?

Answer (score 1):

Create a launcher file for the script. A launcher file is a text file with specific format and `.desktop` extension, as outlined [elsewhere on Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112186/how-do-you-create-a-custom-application-launcher-in-gnome-shell).

The line that defines the command that must be run is the line starting with `Exec=`. The parser for that line is rather primitive: you only can provide it with a single command and arguments. There are a couple of ways around that:

1) Create a wrapper script containing the commands and call the wrapper script on the `Exec=` line

2) Launch `bash` with the `-c` argument.

For approach 2), more practical for just a few commands, your specific `Exec=` line would appear as:

```
Exec=sh -c "cd /home/bmshamsnahid/Android/Sdk/emulator && ./emulator -avd Pixel_2_XL_API_29"
```

Create the `.desktop` file in `.local/share/applications` if it is only for you (no root permissions needed), or in `/usr/share/applications` if the launcher must be available for all users. Correctly formatted `.desktop` files in any of these directories will automatically appear in your application menu, from where you can optionally pin it to the Dock.